# Create a simple login form with AJAX, php, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a login form like this:
I have 3 files: `index.html`, `login.php`, `custom.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>  
  </head>
  <body>    
    <section>
      <div id="message"></div>    
      <form id="loginform" method="POST">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size=25  />
        </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" id="password" name="password" size=25 />
        </p>
        <button id="login" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
      </form>    
    </section>   
  </body>
</html>
```

`custom.js` looks this way:

```
$('#login').click ( function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'login.php',
    data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      //alert(data.message);
      // print into ( <div id="message"></div>) on file html.               
    },
  });
  return false;
});
```

`login.php` looks this way:

```
$users = array(
  0 => array(
    "username" => "admin",
    "password" => "admin",
  ),
  1 => array(
    "username" => "demo",
    "password" => "demo",
  ),
);
```

Please check my code below:

```
for ( $i=0; $i< count($users) ; $i++ ){
  if ( isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password']) ) {
    // Please check this code
    if ( $_POST['username'] == $users[$i]['username'] && $_POST['password'] == $users[$i]['password'] ) {
      $data = array('result' => 'success','message' => 'Message sent from server');
      echo json_encode($data);
      // Please check this code
    } else {
      // Please check this code
      $data = array('result' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Message not sent from server');
      echo json_encode($data);
    }
  }
}
```

I want to check user (array) with users from Form login, use AJAX print message if match user or not.

Please help me check all my code and fix it. Thanks all.

Comment: Is there some actual problem that you forgot to describe?  "Please check my code" isn't really an answerable question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand you, i mean the part with i+.... but...can t you just query the table like: query roucount where user = @_post[user] AND password = @_post[pass], then if mysqli rowcount ==1 login, else die+error?

Comment: No use mysql. I want to check login information from form with $ _POST ['username'], $ _ POST ['password']. How do I code?

Answer (score 0):

What ist the problem?

`$i=0; $i< count($users) ; $i++ )`
Looks like a bug for me.

Try $i<= count $users.

Comment: I want to compare $ _POST ['username'], $ _ POST ['password'] with $ users array. How do I code?

Answer (score 0):

First, your custom.js need to check the result is success or not.

```
$('#login').click ( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'login.php',
        data: $('#loginform').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            // Check the result from data
            if (data.result == 'success') {
                $('#message').html('success');
            } else {
                $('#message').html('fail');
            }
        },
        error: function(d) {
            $('#message').html('error');
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

Second, your login.php returning all the json even login success or not, so it should update to like this

```
for ( $i=0; $i< count($users) ; $i++ ){
    if ( isset($_POST['username'])&& isset($_POST['password']) ) {
        if ( $_POST['username'] == $users[$i]['username'] && $_POST['password'] == $users[$i]['password'] ) {
            $data = array('result' => 'success', 'message' => 'Message sent from server');
            echo json_encode($data);
            // Add return to prevent echo multi json result
            return;
        }
    }
}

// Move the fail code outside the loop otherwise will keep echo fail json
$data = array('result' => 'fail', 'message' => 'Message not sent from server');
echo json_encode($data);
return;
```

This is just a simple solution base on your code, storing a non-encrypted password in PHP is not the best solution.

full code
https://gist.github.com/stanleybz/ad795c599d9db68e0e28bf6d979ae190

Comment: I run your code, but it always reported FAIL, even though I entered the correct user information. please help me.

Comment: Have you tried the full code from my gist? and could you check is the PHP returning the right JSON which something like `{'result': 'fail', 'message': 'Message not sent from server'}` from `console.log(data)` in ajax

Comment: Yep. I tried full code. It's not running. When I copy it to my code, it only shows fail.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8eef35b36eb2547286f531de7eee8630f7b225f8

This is the code for testing PHP response, you should ensure your code on PHP run smoothly by inputting the row 13,14 on your server.

By the way, your reply content is hard for us to solve your question, please try all you can to debug your code step by step.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I'm new to php, ajax. Thanks for your help a lot. I think $ _POST ['username'], $ _POST ['password'] will get the value from the form rather than $ _POST ['username'] = 'admin';
$ _POST ['password'] = 'admin';

Comment: If possible please help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Move your script just above your close body tag, I've comment on your gist

Comment: I moved the script tag above your close body tag. But, nothing changed.

Comment: Have you tried to send a POST request by some tools like [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/postman) to check your PHP run correctly